# QMdiArea does not emit customContextMenuRequested signal

Tags: qt, qt4, contextmenu, qt4.8

I created `QMdiArea` in the main window, then I want to right click on the MDI area to get pop-up menu. To do this, I placed the following code in the constructor in the main window.

```
this->ui->mdiArea->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(this->ui->mdiArea, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(slotRtClickContextMenu(const QPoint&)))
```

The ContextMenu event happened as I checked it in the eventFilter.

However, there is no any response when I click at the MDI area. Then I replaced `this->ui->mdiArea` with this, it worked well and showed the pop-up menu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue but with QTreeWidget.Then setting the value of QtreeWidget->setContextMenuPolicy to Qt::CustomContextMenu resolved the problem.
u could try the same.